# Correct links and references after changing chapter number/letter

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to change the numbering for some chapters from numbers to letters, using:

```
\documentclass{report}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Reference to chapter 1: \ref{chapter_1}

Reference to chapter A: \ref{chapter_a}

\chapter{A chapter}
\label{chapter_1}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%
\chapter{Another one}
\label{chapter_a}

\end{document}
```

Of course, using `\setcounter{chapter}{0}`, I end up with two chapters "1", one denoted as a number, the other as a letter, which messes up the clickable references from `hyperref` (in the example above, both clickable references lead to the first chapter).

Is there a way to solve that -- change one chapter to use a letter instead of a number, without messing up the references by resetting the chapter number?

Comment: Your question can be solved by adding the option 'hypertexnames=false' to `hyperref`. But, this has alredy been asked here on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility: Use `\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{otherchapter\thechapter}` to prevent the doubled chapter counter values which confuses `hyperref`, because this sets the link anchors.

```
\documentclass{report}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Reference to chapter 1: \ref{chapter_1}

Reference to chapter A: \ref{chapter_a}

\chapter{A chapter}
\label{chapter_1}


%\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{otherchapter\thechapter}
\chapter{Another one}
\label{chapter_a}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add option `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}`

```
\documentclass{report}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Reference to chapter 1: \ref{chapter_1}

Reference to chapter A: \ref{chapter_a}

\chapter{A chapter}
\label{chapter_1}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%
\chapter{Another one}
\label{chapter_a}


\end{document}
```

option `[hypertexnames=false]` allows to use hyperrref's counters, but not TeX ones corresponding to `\usepackage{hyperref}`, which is actually `\usepackage[hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}`

Comment: `hypertexnames=false` is only the last resort method, actually